# Intellij IDEA custom language plugin - highlight numbers in string parameter of a method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, colors, syntax-highlighting, intellij-plugin

Question is pretty straightforward.

I use Intellij IDEA for coding.
I want my piece of code colored on simple condition.

I am attaching an image for better reference.

Imagine I have the following code:

[image]

And I want this string literal to be highlighted applying the following conditions.

- numbers (like 123) - be BOLD and BLUE
- string (anything wrapped in '') - be BOLD and ORANGE

How can I achieve this?
I think I need some advises on IDEA plugins or some other way?

Comment: Not possible in IDEA itself as it has only 'Escape sequence', 'Highlighted reference' and 'String' in' Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Language Defaults | String. There are highlight plugins (Preferences | Plugins | Marketplace), but I don't see the one which can do what you need - some plugin which can highlight based on a regex. As a manual workaround, you can use regex in a search field, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-finding-and-replacing-text-using-regular-expressions.html

Comment: This is possible by writing own plugin. As an example it could be SQL language injection. Or JSON language injection. My purpose is very easy because my input string doesn't have any structure of statement. The problem is that I haven't found any references or code examples to achieve smth similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/syntax-highlighting-and-error-highlighting.html#annotator) and [this](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/annotator.html) out.

Here is the sample codes from the link.

```
final class SimpleAnnotator implements Annotator {

  // Define strings for the Simple language prefix - used for annotations, line markers, etc.
  public static final String SIMPLE_PREFIX_STR = "simple";
  public static final String SIMPLE_SEPARATOR_STR = ":";

  @Override
  public void annotate(@NotNull final PsiElement element, @NotNull AnnotationHolder holder) {
    // Ensure the PSI Element is an expression
    if (!(element instanceof PsiLiteralExpression literalExpression)) {
      return;
    }

    // Ensure the Psi element contains a string that starts with the prefix and separator
    String value = literalExpression.getValue() instanceof String ? (String) literalExpression.getValue() : null;
    if (value == null || !value.startsWith(SIMPLE_PREFIX_STR + SIMPLE_SEPARATOR_STR)) {
      return;
    }

    // Define the text ranges (start is inclusive, end is exclusive)
    // "simple:key"
    //  01234567890
    TextRange prefixRange = TextRange.from(element.getTextRange().getStartOffset(), SIMPLE_PREFIX_STR.length() + 1);
    TextRange separatorRange = TextRange.from(prefixRange.getEndOffset(), SIMPLE_SEPARATOR_STR.length());
    TextRange keyRange = new TextRange(separatorRange.getEndOffset(), element.getTextRange().getEndOffset() - 1);

    // highlight "simple" prefix and ":" separator
    holder.newSilentAnnotation(HighlightSeverity.INFORMATION)
        .range(prefixRange).textAttributes(DefaultLanguageHighlighterColors.KEYWORD).create();
    holder.newSilentAnnotation(HighlightSeverity.INFORMATION)
        .range(separatorRange).textAttributes(SimpleSyntaxHighlighter.SEPARATOR).create();


    // Get the list of properties for given key
    String key = value.substring(SIMPLE_PREFIX_STR.length() + SIMPLE_SEPARATOR_STR.length());
    List<SimpleProperty> properties = SimpleUtil.findProperties(element.getProject(), key);
    if (properties.isEmpty()) {
      holder.newAnnotation(HighlightSeverity.ERROR, "Unresolved property")
          .range(keyRange)
          .highlightType(ProblemHighlightType.LIKE_UNKNOWN_SYMBOL)
          // ** Tutorial step 19. - Add a quick fix for the string containing possible properties
          .withFix(new SimpleCreatePropertyQuickFix(key))
          .create();
    } else {
      // Found at least one property, force the text attributes to Simple syntax value character
      holder.newSilentAnnotation(HighlightSeverity.INFORMATION)
          .range(keyRange).textAttributes(SimpleSyntaxHighlighter.VALUE).create();
    }
  }

}
```

You can also use [LivePlugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7282-liveplugin) or [Flora](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/17669-flora-beta-) without creating new plugin.